# ValueError: Cannot assign "{'interests': ['Technology', 'Sports', 'Health'] "Consumer.interests" must be a "Interests" instance

Tags: python, reactjs, django, serialization, model

This is a Django + ReactJS Application where Django is the API backend and the ReactJS is the frontend.

In the signup form when the user tries to register an account it returns an error

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "['Sports', 'Health']": "Consumer.interests" must be a "Interests" instance.
```

Unfortunately, the SOF answers didn't help resolve the issue so I'm asking for your help.

The registration API

```py
class RegistrationAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Request: ", request.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        print(request.data.get('is_consumer'))

        if request.data.get('is_consumer') == 'True':
            consumer_data = request.data.get('additional')

            interest_data = consumer_data.get('interests')
            #interest_data = consumer_data.getlist('interests')
            print("the data is ", interest_data)
            dob_values  = consumer_data.get("dob")
            dob         = get_dob(dob_values)
            age         = get_age(dob_values)
            gender      = consumer_data.get("gender")

            Consumer.objects.create(
                user=user, interests=interest_data, dob=dob, age=age, gender=gender)

                User.objects.filter(pk=user.pk).update(is_consumer=True)
            elif request.data.get('is_business') == 'True':
                Business.objects.create(
                    user=user, **request.data.get('additional'))
                User.objects.filter(pk=user.pk).update(is_business=True)
    
            # if serializer.is_valid():
            #     user = send_verification_email(request, serializer)
    
    
            # email sending for confirmation
            email_subject   = 'Activate your account'
            email_body      = 's'
    
            send_mail(
                email_subject,
                email_body,
                settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
                {user.email,},
            )
    
            return Response({"user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data, "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1]})
```

The Registration Serializer

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password',
                  'is_consumer', 'is_business')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
        model = Consumer
        fields = ('user','interests')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data
        user = User.objects.create_user(user_data.get('username'),
                                        user_data.get('email'),
                                        user_data.get('password'))

        consumer = Consumer.objects.create(user=user, interests=validated_data.get('interests'))
        consumer.save()
        return user
```

The Interests Serializer

```
class InterestsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Interests
        fields = ('technology', 'sports', 'health', 'diy', 'gaming', 'music', 'books', 'art',
                  'science', 'architecture', 'business', 'history', 'finance', 'biology', 'languages')
```

The User Model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    #token = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    is_consumer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_business = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email_confirmation = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The Consumer Model

```
class Consumer(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
        ('Other', 'Other')
    )

    INTERESTS_CHOICES = (
        ('Sports', 'Sports'),
        ('Technology', 'Technology'),
        ('Health', 'Health'),
        ('DIY', 'DIY'),
        ('Gaming', 'Gaming'),
        ('Music', 'Music'),
        ('Books', 'Books'),
        ('Art', 'Art'),
        ('Science', 'Science'),
        ('Architecture', 'Architecture'),
        ('Business', 'Business'),
        ('History', 'History'),
        ('Finance', 'Finance'),
        ('Biology', 'Biology'),
        ('Languages', 'Languages')
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, related_name='consumer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    interests = models.ForeignKey(Interests, related_name='interests', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # interests = models.ForeignKey(Interests, related_name='interests', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    balance = models.FloatField(default=0)
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Where is the consumer Model?

Comment: I've edited the question and added it

Answer (score 0):

Consumer-Interests relationship shall be many-to-many not one-to-many (ForeignKey) so change field type, makemigrations, migrate and try again.

Comment: <class 'user_manage.admin.ConsumerAdmin'>: (admin.E109) The value of 'list_display[4]' must not be a ManyToManyField.  

This is the error I got. Please check your mailbox